# Moment of Inertia using centre of mass knowing distance and weight of rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, vibrations, inertia

I know the mass, I know the center of gravity position. Can i use this to work out the moment of inertia of a rod.

So my ruler is 30 cm long and I know its mass to be 11.8g
I have some blu tac which is towards the end of the ruler (away from the pivot) which weights approx 6.7grams at 30 cm apart. I move my blu tac along the ruler and therefore change its centre of gravity

---

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking if it is possible, or how you would go about actually calculating the moment of inertia?

Comment: so i want to find a relationship between my centre of mass and moment of inertia

Comment: The moments of inertia depend on the exact size and shape of your ruler, it's total mass, and the axis around which it is spinning. the same goes for the blu tac.

Comment: Parallel axis theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Modelling the ruler as a uniform rod, its moment of inertia about its centre of mass is given by $\frac{ML^2}{12}$, where M is its mass and L is its length. If we let the blu tac have mass $m$ and be a distance $x$ from the centre of the ruler, it has moment of intertia $mx^2$ about the centre of the ruler. The total moment of inertia about the centre of the ruler is therefore $\frac{ML^2}{12} + mx^2$.

To find the moment of inertia of the system about its centre of mass, apply the parallel axis theorem. The centre of mass of the system is a distance $\frac{mx}{m+M}$ from that of the rod, so the total moment of inertia is:

$$\frac{ML^2}{12} + mx^2 - \frac{m^2 x^2}{m+M}$$